# Create mongo change stream in the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, changestream, mongodb-3.6

MongoDB introduced [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) in their 3.6 release.
I wanted to implement mongo change stream in my code and wanted to understand how it works. I will implement using the java driver and it's pretty clear.
But I wanted to know if there is there any way to open a change stream on in the mongo shell? Couldn't find much resources on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `db.collection.watch` command opens a c[hange stream cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#changestreams).

For example:

```
watchCursor = db.getSiblingDB("data").sensors.watch(
   [
      { $match : {"operationType" : "insert" } }
   ]
)

while (!watchCursor.isExhausted()){
   if (watchCursor.hasNext()){
      print(tojson(watchCursor.next()));
   }
}
```

Plenty more detail [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/).

Comment: Good idea to make that more obvious. I have updated the answer to include this: `print(tojson(watchCursor.next()));`.